# How to reduce width of tab item in TabLayout in android?

Tags: android, tabitem, indicator

I need to reduce width of tab item in `TabLayout`. I have spent much time to find solutions but seems it's not that easy. Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager_chapter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
   android:id="@+id/tabs_chapter"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change **android:layout_width="match_parent"** to **android:layout_width="wrap_content"** inside  TabLayout view

Answer (score 0):

This may work!

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Comment: Thanks. This will hide tab items.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/primaryColor"
        app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabMode="auto" />
```